# Where to look on error SP2-0317 Expected symbol name is missing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have an Oracle procedure and it is getting this error.  When I look it up online, I get the following helpful message:

> Cause: SQL*Plus was expecting a symbol, but it was not specified.
>
> Actions: Check the syntax of the command you used for the correct
> options.

Those actions are pretty nebulous.  Check for what symbols, where?  Where do I even begin to look to resolve this error?

(I've finally already found the answer, but because it appears to have caught others on my team too, I wanted to post the question and answer here.  I could post the code, but when I was still looking, I didn't know where in the code to even look, I couldn't cut it down to a manageable size, and posting proprietary code is not appropriate.  Plus, it turned out the problem was in comments, not in code at all.)

Comment: Not a question.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have comments or may be your output string contain an `'&'` sign.

`'&'`should be followed by a substitution variable in SQL* Plus

Comment: Yes, the comments included an ampersand.  But, because the documentation is so nebulous, it didn't lead me to that.  Thus the need for a SO entry.